# Implementing a proxy manager plugin for Safari, like ProxyPlus for Google Chrome

Tags: safari, proxy

Google Chrome has ProxyPlus and Firefox has FoxyProxy among others. I was wondering why Safari has no counterpart in its Plugin gallery. There seems to be great need for such stuff in countries where Internet is censored.

I would like to develop one myself. But firstly I would like to know whether it is possible using Apple's API and whether Apple allows such extension. And if so, why no one ever comes up with it?

Any pointer about APIs are also welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: I find it extremely annoying that Safari only is able to use the system wide proxy settings. In my case I would like to exclude Safari from the System wide setting.

Comment: Yeah, it's so 'Apple'. If they think one feature is important, they make it really great. If they think one use case is for minority, they make it very difficult to do, if possible.